# Prove that $G$ is not an open set in $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, solution-verification

> **Prove:** The set $G = \{ X \in\mathbb R^2 : d(X,0) \le 1\}$ is not open in $\mathbb R^2$.
> (Here $X=(x,y), 0=(0,0)$)

We will attempt to prove G is not open in $R^2$ by contradiction.

Let $x=1, y=0$ then by the restrictions imposed on $G$:

$d(X, 0) = \sqrt{(1 - 0)^2 + (0 - 0)^2} = \sqrt{1} = 1$

Thus $(1, 0) \in G$. Let $a = (1, 0)$.

Let us assume $G$ is open, by definition, there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B_\epsilon(a) \in G$.

Let $\epsilon > 0, r > 0$ and $r < \epsilon$ then $(1 + r,0) \in B_\epsilon(a)$. Let $b = (1 + r, 0)$.

Again by the restrictions imposed on G:

$d(b, 0) = \sqrt{((1 + r) - 0)^2 + (0 - 0)^2}$ = $\sqrt{(1 + r)^2}$ = $1 + r$.

Since $r > 0$ then $d(b, 0) > 1$ by the restrictions of $G$, $b \notin G, B_\epsilon(a) ∉ G$.

This is a contradiction meaning $G$ is not open in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Just stylistically, I would tend not to use an asterisk as a variable. I'm not really an analyst but I also am not really a fan of your proof but I will leave it to someone else to give an answer.

Comment: Don't make wrong statements even in the  title. Change it to 'Is $G$ an open set in $\mathbb R^{2}$?'

Comment: You proved correctly that $G$ is not open. Just write $d(b,0)=1+r>0$ to make things more simple. That observation is acceptable.

Comment: The proof is correct. I agree with stuart stevenson that it is probably not a good idea to use * as a variable symbol (and also: here *=1+r, so maybe just write 1+r), but I'm not sure why he says he's not a fan of your proof: it seems to me like pretty much the only sensible proof.

Comment: The proof is correct, and I upvoted your post. But the title was confusing since you actually show that $G$ is not open! In fact, it is closed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an easier approach:

The map $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}: X \mapsto d(X,0)$ is continuous. Consequently, the set $G= f^{-1}(]-\infty,1])$ is a non-empty, proper closed subset of $\Bbb{R}^2$. Since $\Bbb{R}^2$ is connected, $G$ can't be open.